# R scale fill manual - two colors for one value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a map of the US that shows different products for various states.  Each product is associated with one solid color so that each state is color either red, white or blue.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(zoo)
library(DT)
library(tidylog)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(devtools)
library(stringr)
library(mapproj)
library(scales)
library(sf)
library(urbnmapr)



#map of all states using the urbnmapr package

states_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "states", sf = TRUE)

#dividing out the contract types for each state

first.dollar <- states_sf %>%
  filter(state_name %in% c("Washington", "Nebraska", "Florida", "New York", "Maryland")) 

mbi <- states_sf %>%
  filter(state_name %in% c("California", "Massachusetts"))

first.dollar.and.excess.of.loss <- states_sf %>% 
  filter(state_name %in% ("Indiana"))

excess.of.loss <- states_sf %>% 
  filter(!state_name %in% mbi$state_name & !state_name %in% first.dollar$state_name & !state_name %in% first.dollar.and.excess.of.loss$state_name)

#making a theme for the map that removes axes
ditch_the_axes <- theme(
  axis.text = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  axis.title = element_blank()
  )

#transferring the data into the fills
service.contract.map <- states_sf %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(), 
          fill = "grey", color = "#ffffff", size = 0.25) +
  geom_sf(data = excess.of.loss, aes(fill = "Excess of Loss")) +
  geom_sf(data = first.dollar.and.excess.of.loss, aes(fill = "First Dollar / Excess")) +
  geom_sf(data = first.dollar, aes(fill = "First Dollar")) +
  geom_sf(data = mbi,  aes(fill = "MBI")) +

  #assigning color values to the fills
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Excess of Loss" = "dodgerblue1", "First Dollar" = "white", "MBI" = "red", "First Dollar / Excess" = "lightblue2"))
```

You can see the variable "First Dollar / Excess" is a particular state (Indiana) that has two products. Right now I am filling it separately as lightblue2. Is there any way to use a gradient fill of 2 colors for just this state?   Even more ideal would be for it to be colored blue with diagonal white lines across it.

Comment: I think you're looking for scale_*_gradient: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html

Comment: I did try to use scale_fill_gradient on just the first dollar / excess value, but I wasn't able to keep my scale fill manual for the rest of the states and add the gradient layer for just the one state.

Comment: Can you provide a reprex? This will make it easier to troubleshoot: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added all the code, hopefully the comments make it clear what I am doing at each step.  You'll notice that right now the scale fill manual just has a solid color for first dollar / excess, this is the one I want to make a mix of 2 colors.